# jdbc odbc connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, image, jdbc

am a newbie to java. I want to create a table in MYSQL and insert images into it.I have to write code in java to insert the images. can anyone tell me how to give connectivity between mySQL and java code. Can u suggest some materials for jdbc odbc connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even *think* about mentioning ODBC when you're talking Java. JDBC-ODBC bridges were useful once, when we didn't have proper drivers but they should be considered a crime against humanity nowadays :-)

What you want is a type-4 (pure Java) JDBC driver and the "official" one is [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j.html).

That page also has links to a [short JDBC Basics course](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and a [more in-depth one](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Database/JDBCShortCourse/index.html), for your education.